# Where can I ask about UK Government policy?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following.

> **Why has the UK Government moved away from "Ministry of..." names?**
>
> Traditionally, UK Government departments were named "Ministry of [blar]". For example,
>
> - Ministry of Transport
> - Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food
> - Ministry of Education
>
> In recent years, many of these have been retired in favour of "Department for [blar]". For example,
>
> - Ministry of Transport → Department for Transport
> - Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food → Department for Environment, Food and Rural Affairs
> - Ministry of Education → Department for Education
>
> Why is Britain getting rid of its "Ministries" and replacing them with "Departments"?

Where can I ask this?

Answer (score 6):

I believe an appropriate site to ask questions like this is [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) SE. Nonetheless, you should first check their [Help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help) to confirm this for your specific questions, as well as to help determine how to best structure them for their site.

Comment: Thanks! I have asked about it on the [Politics Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6003/39976).